# Details about DDoS protection for Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure-static-web-app, azure-ddos

We are using [Azure Static Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps) for hosting a web-precense.

Right now I am asking myself, if/how an Azure SWA is DDos protected.

As the SWA is not part of a VNET, the optional [Azure DDoS Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/ddos-faq#what-are-the-supported-protected-resource-types-) can not be applied.

References I found so far:

- "Globally distributed static content, putting content closer to your users."[[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview#key-features) This smells like a CDN, which would be a good indicator for having a DDoS protection somehow, but I can't find any details
- "Services running on Azure are inherently protected by the default infrastructure-level DDoS protection."[[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/ddos-faq#are-services-unsafe-in-azure-without-the-service-) Ok so somehow every service in Azure has  a default DDos protection, but I can't find any details

Is an Azure Static Web App DDoS protected? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Azure DDoS Basic is built into the platform and enabled for all services. You can find some details of what that offers, vs the standard offering, [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-ddos-protection-for-virtual-networks-generally-available/). DDoS standard is the more user configurable option, but as you say this is only available when using a vNet.

[image]